# Why passing value-returning function works fine on operator function to overload = operator and not on others?

Tags: c++, oop, reference, operator-overloading, return-value

Look at this code:

```
class test
{
    int x;
 
 public:
    test ()
    {
        x = 3;
    }
};
test returnObj (test &obj)
{
    return obj;    
}

int main ()
{
    test object;
    returnObj (returnObj (object)); // line A
    return 0;
}
```

This code will give error at line A because we are passing return by value function as an actual parameter where it accepts only reference. So far so good. It makes sense.

Assume that we have overloaded **=** and **+** operator for class test. Now look at this:

```
test a, b;
test d = a + b;
```

This code will create two object of type test, add them and assign the result to object d. But the prototype of operator function to overload + operator is :

```
test operator+ (const test&) const;
```

That means a + b will return the resultant object by value which is then to be passed to the operator function which overloads **=** operator, whose prototype is:

```
test& operator= (const test&);
```

Which clearly shows that it accepts only reference. So why does the compiler not give error here. (btw please tell what returning an object by value actually means)

Answer (score 1):

The difference is the word `const`. The rule in C++ is that you cannot bind a non-const reference to a temporary.

That's why the first example doesn't work. Return values from functions are one kind of temporary and the `returnObj` function parameter is a non-const reference. If you change `test returnObj (test &obj)` to `test returnObj (const test &obj)` it will compile.

But in the second example `operator=` takes a const reference, and that makes all the difference.

Returing an object by value just means a function whose return type is not a reference.

Comment: Except that in the second case, `test d = a + b; ` does not actually use `operator=` at all, it is just syntax sugar for `test d(a + b);` so it will actually use the copy constructor instead, which in this case will be implicitly generated by the compiler as `test(const test&)`.

Comment: so why do we not use a const reference with ostream object in overloading << operator? `friend ostream& operator << (ostream&, const className&);`

Comment: @BilalSheikh Because the output methods of `ostream` are not const methods. So using `const ostream&` would mean that you couldn't call most of the ostream methods (try it and see). Understanding `const` is very important in C++.